# API to get AppContainerName from AppContainerSid

Tags: c++, winapi, kernel, sid

Say, if I have a `DACL` for a process that I need to show for an end-user. I can convert it to string representation with `ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor`. I then need to make it a little bit more manageable for the user by removing "crazy" local SIDs from it. Here's an example:

```
D:(A;;0x1fffff;;;S-1-5-21-2301966995-2804055512-1978750589-1002)(A;;0x1fffff;;;SY)(A;;0x121411;;;S-1-5-5-0-1207601)(A;;0x1fffff;;;S-1-15-2-155514346-2573954481-755741238-1654018636-1233331829-3075935687-2861478708)
```

For instance, the resulting string may include a user SID (or `S-1-5-21-2301966995-2804055512-1978750589-1002` in the case above), which I can convert to a user name with [`LookupAccountName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but I can't seem to find a way to convert AppContainer SIDs into AppContainer name.

In this case, `S-1-15-2-155514346-2573954481-755741238-1654018636-1233331829-3075935687-2861478708` stands for `Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost`.

There's an API that can convert the latter into the former, called [`DeriveAppContainerSidFromAppContainerName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

But I'm curious how do I convert `AppContainerSid` into `AppContainerName`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for this task exist undocumented function (look [*app_container.cc*](https://github.com/ChromiumWebApps/chromium/blob/master/sandbox/win/src/app_container.cc#L155)
from chromium
)

```
LONG WINAPI AppContainerLookupMoniker(PSID Sid, PWSTR* packageFamilyName);
```

it exported from `api-ms-win-appmodel-identity-l1-2-0.dll`

it take your sid as input and return string - *packageFamilyName*. for free this string need use another undocumented api

```
BOOLEAN WINAPI AppContainerFreeMemory(void* ptr);
```

returned *packageFamilyName* we can use already in documented api [`GetPackagesByPackageFamily`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446613(v=vs.85).aspx). returned *packageFullName* we already can use in api like [`GetStagedPackagePathByFullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn270606(v=vs.85).aspx), [`OpenPackageInfoByFullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446768(v=vs.85).aspx), etc..

for example:

```
#include <appmodel.h>

void AppXtest(PSID Sid)
{
    LONG (WINAPI* AppContainerLookupMoniker)(PSID Sid, PWSTR* packageFamilyName);
    BOOLEAN (WINAPI* AppContainerFreeMemory)(void* ptr);

    if (HMODULE hmod = LoadLibraryW(L"api-ms-win-appmodel-identity-l1-2-0"))
    {
        if ((*(void**)&AppContainerLookupMoniker = GetProcAddress(hmod, "AppContainerLookupMoniker")) &&
            (*(void**)&AppContainerFreeMemory = GetProcAddress(hmod, "AppContainerFreeMemory")))
        {

            PWSTR packageFamilyName;
            LONG err = AppContainerLookupMoniker(Sid, &packageFamilyName);

            if (err == NOERROR)
            {
                DbgPrint("%S\n", packageFamilyName);

                UINT32 count = 0, bufferLength = 0;

                if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetPackagesByPackageFamily(packageFamilyName, &count, 0, &bufferLength, 0))
                {
                    PWSTR *packageFullNames = (PWSTR*)alloca(count * sizeof(PWSTR) + bufferLength*sizeof(WCHAR));
                    PWSTR buffer = (PWSTR)(packageFullNames+ count);

                    if (NOERROR == GetPackagesByPackageFamily(packageFamilyName, &count, packageFullNames, &bufferLength, buffer))
                    {
                        if (count)
                        {
                            do 
                            {
                                PCWSTR packageFullName = *packageFullNames++;
                                DbgPrint("%S\n", packageFullName);

                                WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
                                UINT32 len = RTL_NUMBER_OF(path);

                                if (NOERROR == GetStagedPackagePathByFullName(packageFullName, &len, path))
                                {
                                    DbgPrint("%S\n", path);
                                }
                            } while (--count);
                        }
                    }
                }

                AppContainerFreeMemory(packageFamilyName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for sid `S-1-15-2-155514346-2573954481-755741238-1654018636-1233331829-3075935687-2861478708`

i got:

```
microsoft.windows.shellexperiencehost_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.14393.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy
```

Comment: Oh man, you beat me to it by like 10 minutes. I found it as well by stepping into `DeriveAppContainerSidFromAppContainerName` with a debugger. Just curious though, what's that `cw5n1h2txyewy` whatyamacallit at the end? Is there a way to get rid of it? Otherwise it looks like a buffer overrun junk. (That's what took me most of the time to figure out. I thought initially that I'm messing up the buffer size somewhere.)

Comment: @c00000fd no, `cw5n1h2txyewy` not buffer overrun. look under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Mappings\S-1-15-2-155514346-2573954481-755741238-1654018636-1233331829-3075935687-2861478708` key

Comment: It is there to make the name unique. It think it is explained on one of the MSDN blogs. It is tied to your store developer account IIRC.

Comment: @Anders: Hmm, interesting. Thanks. Also if I do `DeriveAppContainerSidFromAppContainerName(L"Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost", &sid);` it succeeds. But then if I do this on that SID: `AppContainerLookupMoniker(sid, &moniker);` it fails with error code `0x80070002` or `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: @c00000fd `DeriveAppContainerSidFromAppContainerName` is **always** succeeds. for **any** name. because it simply convert name to low case and than compute sha-256 hash on it. and use first 7 dword from hash for create sid `s-1-15-2-h[0]-h[1]-h[2]-h[3]-h[4]-h[5]-h[6]`. the last 8 dword from hash simply ignored

Comment: @RbMm: Oh, that's what that stuff is. I was wondering why was it calling some crypto functions internally. Now it makes sense. (Well, no, actually it doesn't. For instance, why wouldn't it check `pszAppContainerName` to be valid first.) As a side note, the more I look into the internals of WinAPIs the more I see some weird "round-and-about" implementation.